# PHPUnit - How to instantiate my pdo class in PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpunit

How can I instantiate my pdo class in PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase?

for instance, this is my `\test\SuitTest.php`,

```
namespace Test;

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

class SuiteTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $PDO = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->PDO = new \Foo\Adaptor\PdoAdaptor(); // the pdo is not instantiated at all - I think!
    }

    protected function truncateTables ($tables)
    {
        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $this->PDO->truncateTable($table);
        }
    }

    /**
     * DO NOT DELETE, REQUIRED TO AVOID FAILURE OF NO TESTS IN FILE
     * PHPUnit is ignoring the exclude in the phpunit.xml config file
     */
    public function testDummyTest()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to use the pdo class that I use it for development and production, which is in, `\app\source\Adaptor\PdoAdaptor.php`,

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Adaptor;

use PDO;

class PdoAdaptor
{
    protected $PDO = null;
    protected $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phpunit', $username = 'root', $password = 'xxxx';

    /*
     * Make the pdo connection.
     * @return object $PDO
     */
    public function connect()
    {
        try {
            $this->PDO = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            $this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // Unset props.
            unset($this->dsn);
            unset($this->username);
            unset($this->password);
        } catch (PDOException $error) {
            // Call the getError function
            $this->getError($error);
        }
    }

    public function truncateTable($table)
    {
        $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE $table";
        $command = $this->PDO->prepare($sql);
        $command->execute();
    }
}
```

I get this error when I run `phpunit` for testing my codes,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

The pdo is not instantiated at all inside the `construct` method in `SuiteTes`t - I think!

This is my dir structure,

[image]

Comment: Also, your exclude isn't being ignored; that exclude is for code coverage, not which tests should be run

Comment: sorry, i dont get it...

Comment: The comment about phpunit not ignoring your tests in your question; phpunit doesn't ignore tests. It ignores classes when using the `--coverage-*` options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`setUpBeforeClass`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html) method (note: it's static)

```
protected static $pdo;

public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    static::$pdo = new PdoAdapter();
}
```

Then just access your pdo instance with `static::$pdo` or `self::$pdo` in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the setup method instead of overwriting the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase constructor, i.e. just replace the constructor definition in SuiteTest class with:

```
public function setup()
{
    $this->PDO = new \Foo\Adaptor\PdoAdaptor();
}
```